# Pyomo: Iterative model to reach a known value for a given variable

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am new to Pyomo and I am trying to build a simple model.
It takes only one variable with known initial and final values. The solver needs to modify the value of the vafriable to reach its final value while minimizing the change between each timestep.

However when I run my optimization the value of my variable doesn't change over time.

Here is my model:

```
# Define the known initial and final values for the variable x

x_init = 10
x_final = 50

# Define the number of time steps

T = 10

# Create the model

model = ConcreteModel()

# Define the set of time steps

model.T = Set(initialize=range(1, T+1))

# Define the variable x

model.x = Var(model.T, within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=x_init)

# Define the change variable as a Suffix

model.delx = Var(model.T)

# Define the objective function

model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(model.delx[t] for t in model.T), sense=minimize)

# Define the constraints

for t in model.T:
# Define the constraint for reaching the known value
if t == T:
   model.add_component('con_end', Constraint(expr=model.x[T] == x_final))
else:
   # Define the constraint that links to the next time step
   model.add_component('con_link_{}'.format(t), Constraint(expr=model.x[t+1] - model.x[t] == model.delx[t]))

# Solve the model

solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
solver.solve(model)

# Print the optimal value of x at each time step

for t in model.T:
print(f"x[{t}] = {model.x[t].value:.2f}")
```

Comment: Some first remarks: (1) Initialize is not doing what you think.  glpk does not accept initial values.  (2) `model.con_delt` is overwritten.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you, I edited the code based on your remarks. When I p^rint the model I now get the 10 constraints. For the initialize part the value of x does start at the defined initial value so maybe I don't understand that comment. Overall the problem is still the same